# COUNTIF OR COUNTA

Tags: google-sheets, count, sum, google-sheets-formula, countif

[image]How do i use COUNTIF or COUNTA with a condition to count how many none blanks based on criteria across columns.

What i hope to achieve: COUNTA Col B, Col C, Col J and Col F only IF Col A Contains Smith.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hey could you give a sample screenshot of the output to achieve?

Comment: @LucasLui888, Image added. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(SUM((B3:G<>"")*(A3:A="smith")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
=COUNTA(FILTER(B:G,A:A="Smith"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The COUNTA Function is categorized under Excel Statistical functions. It will calculate the number of cells that are not blank within a given set of values.  The COUNTA function is also commonly referred to as the Excel COUNTIF Not Blank formula.

The COUNTA function is useful if we wish to keep a count of cells in a given range. Apart from crunching numbers, we often need to count cells with values. In such a scenario, the function can be useful.